# Evaluate $\iiint e^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}dV$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the triple integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $$\iiint e^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}dV$$

The hint is: $$\int e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt \pi$$

I saw the same exercise here :[$\iiint e^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}dV$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339336/iiint-e-x2-2y2-3z2dv/339343#339343) but I didn't succeeded to finish by myself

$$\iiint e^{-(x^2+2y^2+3z^2)}\,dV=\left(\int e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\left(\int e^{-2y^2}\,dy\right)\left(\int e^{-3z^2}\,dz\right).$$

$$\Longrightarrow \sqrt \pi \underbrace{\left(\int e^{-2y^2}\,dy\right)}_{A}\underbrace{\left(\int e^{-3z^2}\,dz\right)}_{B}$$

> But now how can I evaluate $A,B?$

---

Edit:
After using @Matt B answer the answer that I have got is $\sqrt {\frac{\pi^3}{6}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For A, let $y=t/\sqrt{2}$, so doing the substitution you get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int e^{-t^2} dt$. Similarly take $z=u/\sqrt{3}$ for B to get something similar which you can then apply your hint to.

Comment: but the hint is only for the first int , how can I use the hint for $A,B$?

Comment: @Nehorai the substitution should be $y=t/\sqrt{2}$ as then $-2y^2=-t^2$ which is the form you want to match up to so you can apply your hint. I did however have a typo in the z substitution though which I've amended.